# index is used with SELECT COUNT(1) but not with SELECT *

Tags: sql, mysql, indexing, query-optimization, explain

Here's my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM nhd
WHERE gnis_id IN (01372336);
```

The table definition has an `INDEX gnis_id (gnis_id)` on it and, indeed, that index is used with this query. BUT when I replace the `COUNT(1)` with `*` the index is *not* used, at least according to `EXPLAIN`. Why is that? Why would changing the columns I'm getting back change how MySQL is deciding which INDEX to use for the WHERE part of the query?

Here's the output of the EXPLAIN with `*`:

```
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: nhd
partitions: NULL
type: ALL
possible_keys: gnis_id
key: NULL
key_len: NULL
ref: NULL
rows: 2752840
filtered: 10.00
Extra: Using where
```

Here's the output of `SHOW INDEX FROM nhd`:

https://pastebin.com/KXpqBeJm

I'm running MySQL 8.0.33

Comment: Because one can gather all of the information it needs solely by reading the index while the other requires fetching the records as well. The optimizer takes work like that into consideration.  What percentage of the data matches that predicate? The verbose explain output for both queries would help us understand what is happening. Sometimes updating stays will help

Comment: @user20042973 - with the `WHERE` 96 rows are returned. Without it there are 2,758,717 rows. As for a verbose explain...  is that different than a regular EXPLAIN? I added the output of EXPLAIN to my post for `SELECT *`.

Comment: Can we have the result of `show index` statement ? Cardinality is also a factor which affects whether a possible index shall be used.

Comment: If your select list is beyond the indexed columns and the clusterer index(which is appended at the end of a secondary index), Mysql will either use the clustered index as a pointer to get the missing data from the main table (complete table built upon clustered index) or do a full table scan even if the secondary index fits the table condition.

Comment: @blabla_bingo - here's the output of `SHOW INDEX FROM nhd`: https://pastebin.com/KXpqBeJm

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  I think there is an important clue there.

Comment: Note that `SHOW INDEX` and `EXPLAIN` fail to give the required clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A guess.  Is this the declaration of the column?

```
gnis_id VARCHAR(8)
```

Meanwhile, you are checking those strings against a number:

```
WHERE gnis_id IN (01372336)
```

That means it has to convert each `gnis_id` to a number before testing.

Solution:

```
WHERE gnis_id IN ("01372336")
```

With that change, it will look at only 96 rows, not 2,758,717 rows.  (Actually, it will be 97 rows -- the extra one is to discover that it is finished.)

**Discussion**

`SELECT COUNT(1)` can be done entirely in the `INDEX's` BTree.  That is the index is "covering"; `EXPLAIN` will say "Using index".  And, because the index is ordered by `gnis_id`, the rows it needs to look at are consecutive *once the datatypes match*.

`SELECT *` needs to fetch all the columns, which are found only in the data's BTree.

The clustered index on `id` does not need to be involved.

Comment: Hi Rick, if it's the data type to blame ,I was wondering why MySQL decides to use the index when the SELECT clause is changed to `select count(1)`? I thought it was the `SELECT *` to blame, which requires extra clustered index reference and the index selectivity is low.  Would you please elaborate? Thank you kindly.

Comment: @blabla_bingo - I made a stab at elaborating.

Answer (score 1):

From result of your `SHOW INDEX` statement, we can see the info regarding the table condition `gnis_id`:

```
Table: nhd
Non_unique: 1
Key_name: gnis_id
Seq_in_index: 1
Column_name: gnis_id
Collation: A
Cardinality: 16206
Sub_part: NULL
Packed: NULL
Null:
Index_type: BTREE
Comment:
Index_comment:
Visible: YES
Expression: NULL
```

As the cardinality suggests, the selectivity for the index i.e the cardinality/table_row_count 16206 / 2752840 = 0.0059 is quite low. And by using `select *`, which has items beyond the stored values of the index, should MySQL decide to use the index, it would have to use the clustered key at the end of each index row to refer to the main table. 
With the aboved mentioned two issues:low selectivity and has to use clustered index to refer to main table for missing information, MySQL's optimiser believes it'd better use a FULL TABLE scan (which is based upon the clustered index) instead, as it find the latter one worse in the trade-off between the (FULL TABLE scan) and (extra reference work plus low selectivity).
Here is a couple of things you can try:

First, use `select gnis_id` instead of `select *` ,this will have MySQL use the index as the index covers the value of gnis_id itself, which means no extra reference work is necessary (the same applies to `select count(1)`). You will find the access type to be `ref` in the excution plan, which makes the query response time significantly (hopefully) better than the access type `ALL` which is caused by `select *`.
Secondly, use the `select *` clause but at the end of the from clause add `force index(gnis_id)` to force MySQL to use the index.

```
SELECT *
FROM nhd force index(gnis_id)
WHERE gnis_id IN (01372336);
```

Find how long it takes to execute it and compare how long it takes to execute the one without forcing the index. You will see why MySQL deems it unnecessary to use the index.